# unable to create a IDXGIDevice with D3D12CreateDevice()

Tags: directx12

I was trying to do a bare bones simple build similar to some Directx samples. First I have to use `__uuid()` instead of `IID_PPV_ARGS()` in `D3D12CreateDevice()` in order to get an `HRESULT=S_OK`. But then when I try to create a command queue with `CreateCommandQueue` visual studio says that the device object which is really a com pointer `ComPtr<IDXGIDevice>` doesn't have a member function `CreateCommandQueue`, even though when I look through the `D3D12.h` header I can see it declare it as a public member.

Comment: Let's get the obvious out of the way: are you sure your GPU supports D3D12?

Comment: @I was almost entirely certain, but I figured it out. I was making simple mistake of passing a `ComPtr<IDXGIDevice>` instance pointer instead of a `ComPtr<ID3D12Device>`. So basically the device is supposed to come from `D3D12` not `DXGI`. Some how I forced it to compile and was way off in that mess.

Comment: Then post that as an answer

Answer (score 0):

A bare-minimum would be:

```
ComPtr<ID3D12Device> device;
HRESULT hr = D3D12CreateDevice(nullptr, D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0, IID_PPV_ARGS(&device));
if (FAILED(hr))
    // Error!
```

This will fail if the default device doesn't have an updated WDDM 2.0 driver that supports DirectX 12.

> This program would also fail to run/bind on a system older than Windows 10 because `D3D12CreateDevice` in `d3d12.dll` only exists on Windows 10 systems.

You cannot `QueryInterface` a `IDXIGDevice` from a `ID3D12Device`, nor can you create a `IDXGIDevice` using `D3D12CreateDevice`. This is not supported for Direct3D 12. DXGI is strictly for dealing with adapters, outputs, and swap chains, not Direct3D devices.

See [Anatomy of Direct3D 12 Create Device](https://walbourn.github.io/anatomy-of-direct3d-12-create-device/)

Comment: It has been my experience in fact that you indeed can `D3D12CreateDevice` with result `S_OK` using a device of type `IDXIGDevice` if you `__uuidof(ID3D12Device)` it instead of `IID_PPV_ARGS()` it. Which kinda forces it to a different type (which is why microsoft recommends only using the `IDD_PPV_ARGS()` for querying com interfaces instead of explicitly getting the `RIID` and passing the pointer to the device buffer pointer separately. I managed to fall into this by simply declaring the device of wrong type, `IDXGIDevice` and not `ID3D12Device`. Due to the similar name I just assumed ...cont

Comment: cont...I was using an `ID3D12Device`. As I kept getting an `E_nointerface` from `D3D12CreateDevice` with `IID_PPV_ARGS()` I switched to `__uuidof()`. So to summarize if you use a `ComPtr<IDXIGDevice> and essentially cast it to a `ID3D12Device` for the `RIID`, `D3D12CreateDevice` will return with `S_OK`. It's not till you attempt to get a command queue from it that it refuses. So while I could down vote your answer for being factually incorrect, as my seemingly valid path through this issue was deemed the same thoughtful or rather commentful criticism; I will not bother.

Comment: If you are doing ``ComPtr<IDXIGDevice> device; D3D12CreateDevice(nullptr, D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0, __uuidof(ID3D12Device), &device);`` then what you are getting back isn't a valid ``IDXGIDevice`` interface. Only the ``IUnknown`` interfaces are actually the same in those two interfaces. That's not actually valid COM code to be writing here, so I'm not surprised that you eventually hit something that failed.

Comment: I guess the part of `D3D12CreateDevice` either doesn't or can't check the pointer's type, so assumes the type of the `RIID`. It probably just chooses the interface type to fill into the pointer based on the `RIID`. So it functionally works the same. It's not until the compiler takes a look at the header for a `IDXGIDevice` later on and realizes it "shouldn't" have a `CreateCommandQueue()` method member. At any rate it was a typo probably because I intuitively perceived the Dxgi.dll handles the adapter device creation and not D3d12.dll. Interesting.

Comment: If you look at the actual signature of ``D3D12CreateDevice``, the 4th parameter is ``void**``.  The ``IID_PPV_ARGS`` is not so much a recommendation as the only way to remotely make this type-safe. You are basically doing something like: ``MyClass* ptr = (MyClass*)( new TotallyUnrelatedClass )``